# "Updating" a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

When given a dictionary(db), is there a way to add values to a key that already exist within the dictionary. Hence the updating or simply adding the key and its value if the key doesn't already exist:

Say that:

```
db = {'John': [('Brown', 'Blue', 180)]}
def add_anything(db,Name(the key), HairColor(value), EyeColor(value), Height(value):
add_anything(db, "John", "Black", "Red", "160")
```

and when i updated db, returning db would give back:

```
{'John': [('Brown', 'Blue', 180),('Black', 'Red', 160)]}
```

How would that definition function look like? Thank you

Comment: Other than calling the `append()` method of the list?

Comment: And if there already exists both the key and value, then not allowing duplicates (not adding the info in because its already there)

Comment: It looks as though your values are lists. Do you need to maintain order or is a `set` appropriate? Of course, that limits values to hashable types also.

Comment: There are probably hundreds of questions already addressing this and similar questions. Try to looking for them.

Answer (score 1):

I think the brute force method is the best. Its still short and straight forward

```
def add_anything(d, key, *value):
    if key in d:
        if value not in d[key]:
            d[key].append(value)
    else:
        d[key] = [value]
```

Running a few tests

```
>>> add_anything(d, 'bob', 'Brown', 'Blue', '180')
>>> d
{'bob': [('Brown', 'Blue', '180')]}
>>> add_anything(d, 'bob', 'Brown', 'Blue', '180')
>>> d
{'bob': [('Brown', 'Blue', '180')]}
>>> add_anything(d, 'bob', 'Brown', 'Blue', '666')
>>> d
{'bob': [('Brown', 'Blue', '180'), ('Brown', 'Blue', '666')]}
>>> add_anything(d, 'jane', 'Brown', 'Blue', '666')
>>> d
{'jane': [('Brown', 'Blue', '666')], 'bob': [('Brown', 'Blue', '180'), ('Brown', 'Blue', '666')]}
```

Comment: I thought dictionaries can't use the .append() command, I'm getting a TypeError of 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: The dict's values are lists. `d[key]` gets the list value and `d[key].append()` appends to the list. I added some tests and they run for me, Is your code the same? Which line fails? Can you reproduce the problem with the code I posted and show how you did it? The we can figure this out.

Comment: i'm down to only one failed test case, it looks like the only problem is the ordering of the values, can a sort() command be used or something else

Comment: I changed the examples to take any number of parameters as a tuple instead of a single tuple and your example works for me. About that "TypeError of 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable" - that would happen if you used square brackets with the function call... e.g. `add_anything['bob', 1,2,3]`. What is the exact line that gets that error?

Comment: Sort each value? Yeah, you could do that. One option is to do `d.sort()` right after `d[key].append(value)`.

Comment: The error i was getting was a simply a mistype on my end sorry, but i thought dictionaries couldn't be sorted only its values

Comment: I'm not sure what your final goal is, but `sorted(d.keys())` is one option.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `set` to prevent duplicates but at the cost of losing order which I'm assuming isn't important:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> db = defaultdict(set)
>>> db['John'].add(('Brown', 'Blue', 180))
>>> db
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'John': set([('Brown', 'Blue', 180)])})
>>> db['John'].add(('Brown', 'Blue', 180))
>>> db
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'John': set([('Brown', 'Blue', 180)])})
>>> db['John'].add(("Black", "Red", "160"))
>>> db['Jane'].add(("Red", "Gree", "140"))
>>> db
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'Jane': set([('Red', 'Gree', '140')]), 'John': set([('Brown', 'Blue', 180), ('Black', 'Red', '160')])})
```

Comment: A great answer but only works if values are hashable.

Comment: @tdelaney if this becomes a problem, e.g. if OP wants to insert lists, he/she should convert to the hashable equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Might be missing something here but the faster try/catch (do first then ask forgiveness)?

```
d = {'John': [('Brown', 'Blue', 180)]}

def add_to_dict(d, k, v):
    try:
        d[k].append(v)
    except KeyError:
        d[k] = [v]
    return d

print(d)
add_to_dict(d, "John", ('Black', 'Red', 160))
print(d)
add_to_dict(d, "Jim", ('Blond', 'Green', 200))
print(d)
add_to_dict(d, "Jim", ('Blond', 'Green', 220))
print(d)
```

or the slower if check (ask for permission then do)?

```
def add_to_dict(d, k, v):
    if k in d.keys():
        d[k].append(v)
    else:
        d[k] = [v]
    return d
```